# Error 80040154 (Class not registered exception) when initializing VCProjectEngineObject (Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.dll)

Tags: c#, exception, com, dllregistration

I'm trying to run [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/sln2mak.aspx) tool in order to convert a Visual C++ project to makefile.
The project I'm trying to convert project is written in VS2008, so I'm using a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.dll from version 9.

It fails in this line:

```
VCProjectEngine vcprojEngine = new VCProjectEngineObject();
```

With the following exception:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID
>   {D19A00C4-A7F9-4E14-A5E1-D060B7EB57F3}
>   failed due to the following error:
>   80040154 Class not registered
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
>   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

When tried to register VCProjectEngine.dll with regsvr32, I got an error that the entry point DllRegisterServer was not found.

Any idea??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There are not many good reasons this would fail, especially the regsvr32 step.  Run dumpbin /exports on that dll.  If you don't see DllRegisterServer then you've got a corrupt install.  It should have more side-effects, you wouldn't be able to build C/C++ projects anymore.

One standard failure mode is running this on a 64-bit operating system.  This is 32-bit unmanaged code, you would indeed get the 'class not registered' exception.  Project + Properties, Build tab, change Platform Target to x86.

Comment: The x86 target platform was the issue. Thank you!

Comment: @Hans Passant any more thoughts on this? I am building for x86 platform but still getting an error for a VB6 COM interop. My build machine is Widows server 2008 R2

Comment: You should totally bold that part about x86 - I bet 99% of the time that's what it is!

Comment: @hans : So my application can never behave as a 64bit process ?