# Null exception error 'used before it has been assigned a value'

Tags: vb.net

I got a null exception error in my code and I cannot understand why.

I have an excel file named 'FilterXpath' added to my project in 'Resources'. I have the code the below:

```
Dim FilterXpath As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim w As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.worksheet
Dim sheet As Worksheet

w = FilterXpath.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\sridevi\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsApplication2\WindowsApplication2\Resources\FilterXpath.xlsx")
''I got null exception here stating that FilterXpath is used before it has been assigned a value.
```

Answer (score 1):

declare them as `New` instance

```
Dim FilterXpath As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application 
Dim w As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.worksheet Dim sheet As Worksheet
```

Comment: thanks for the advise.but still i get COM component retrieving error 80040154 in the line 'Dim FilterXpath As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application '

Comment: For this error, check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197506/how-to-repair-comexception-error-80040154