# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID failed due to the following error: 8007045a

Tags: vb.net, componentone

I am new to VB Dot Net. I am using ComponentOne True OLE DbGrid in my form. Now I need to add Value Items to my column.So i tried this:                                                    TDBGrid1.Columns(14).ValueItems.Add(New TrueOleDBGrid80.ValueItem())
        TDBGrid1.Columns(14).ValueItems(2).Value = 2                                         My code is compiling and running well. But when i try to run my exe on client machine it gives me Error: "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID  failed due to the following error: 8007045a " for the above ValueItems.Add() line. Please, help me. Thanks

Comment: It is a Windows error, 1114 = ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED.  The DLL you use returned FALSE from its DllMain() entrypoint.  It is unhappy about something, impossible to guess why.  Look in the Windows event log for a more detailed diagnostic message.  If you don't see one (likely), or can't understand what it says then you'll need to contact the component vendor for support.

Comment: @HansPassant.. I looked into the Windows Event Logs but i dont get anything there. I have registered all my .ocx files(todg8.ocx, todb8.ocx, xadb8.ocx). Cant figure out the issue. It only appears when I use above lines to add a Value Items to my columns and when I comment out the lines it runs OK..

Comment: @HansPassant.. Also I am not able to change the properties of my grid at design time..

Answer (score -1):

The issue seems to be due to difference in the processor on which the application was created and is being run on. You might look for the respective dll in the following locations, use it in your project and see if it solves your issue:
64 bit machine : HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{###}\InprocServer32
32 bit machine : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID{###}\InprocServer32.

A few more suggetions can be found at the following links :

[How to repair COMException error 80040154?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197506/how-to-repair-comexception-error-80040154)

[Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154 VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200452/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-xxxx-failed-due-to-t)

Regards,
Mohita

Answer (score -1):

Try reregistering TdbGrid8 from command line :
regsvr32 c:pathtdbg8.ocx
Thanks,
Richa