# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154 VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I code in VB.net under Visual Studio 2008. I have this error and I don't understand why.

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154

I use a DLL and I want to compile it in 64bit. I have the following code:

```
Imports MetroProDAT_Library

Public Class Data
    Public attr As ZygoDataAttributes
    Public oData As ZygoDataFile

    Public Sub LoadData(ByVal FileName As String)
        Dim idx As Double
        Dim jdx As Double

        oData = New ZygoDataFile  '///this sentence bug
        attr = oData.Attribute
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The COM DLL is almost certainly a 32bit DLL.  IF you app must remain 64bit, you will have to jump thru some hoops to get them to work together.  See this: http://www.scribd.com/doc/56629579/64-Bit-Insider-Volume-1-Issue-7

Comment: See this SO answer
[How to repair COM Exception error 80040154](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197506/how-to-repair-comexception-error-80040154)

Comment: Ok i will try . I think the problem is my library because in 32 bi it works well. I wanted to changed my dll , but is it normal that the path of my dll in visual studio is \Home\Desktop\P4\WindowsApplication3\obj\x64\Debug\Interop.MetroProDAT_Library.dll ?? Visual studio made a copy in a folder ?

Comment: It is works !! thant you !

Answer (score -1):

it might be the dll file. do you have a specific dll files that needed to run the program ?

register it to the machine and test it again