# FAXCOMEXLib Fatal Error when sending fax

Tags: c#, fax

I have written a C# console application that uses FAXCOMEXLib.

The application reads in a text file and submits it to the fax queue.

(1) The fax queue is running on Windows 2003 SBS (and is working fine)

(2) I've developed my application using Visual Studio 2013 Express C# console app.

(3) Running the console app on my Windows 8 Ent development machine works fine, and submits the document and sends successfully

(4) If I deploy the console app to a Windows 2008 server the following happens;

- I had to install the fax service on the local machine, even though the fax is being sent via another fax server, otherwise I get the error `Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {CDA8ACB0-8CF5-4F6C-9BA2-5931D40C8CAE} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).`
- The app runs fine, once the fax service is installed
- The fax is submitted to the fax queue successfully
- I can see the fax status in the queue as Pending, followed by Dialing and then Transmitting.
- However after a while, I get a error Fatal error, and the fax doesn't go.

So the issue isn't with the modem. The log entry on the Windows server is;

The event log entry is

> Event Type: Warning
>   Event Source: Microsoft Fax
>   Event Category: Outbound
>   Event ID: 32028
>   Date: 14/01/2014
>   Time: 15:43:42
>   User: N/A
>   Computer: FAXSERVER
>   Description:
>   An error was encountered while sending a fax. The service will attempt
>   to resend the fax. If further transmissions fail, please verify that
>   the phone line, fax sending device, and fax receiving device are
>   working properly. Sender: . Billing code: . Sender company: . Sender
>   dept: . Device name: U.S. Robotics 56K FAX EXT. Job ID:
>   0x0201cf113f2ab5e7. User name: FAXSERVER\Administrator.
>
> Please check the activity log for further details of this event.

So basically the fax leaves the Windows 2008 server from the C# app. and appears in the queue on the Windows 2003 SBS fax server, but it isn't being sent.

The fax number is fine, and can send a fax using the traditional File-Print (send to fax method in notepad as a example, on the Windows 2008 server), as well as receiving faxes.

How can I over come this issue ?

Comment: Because you have failed to include the most important thing: WHAT is the "FatalError's" message, errorcode, stacktrace, etc, or at least, where do you get it from and how do you observe it? Any logs? Have you checked windows's App and Sys Events, does they contain anything related? Also, have you checked the docs (if any) - in what situations a "FatalError" can be reported? Maybe it's simply a failure during TxRx between machines, as even if it's "transmitting" something can go wrong. If all above is not possible, have you tried talking to the 'FaxComex' tech support?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the log entry.

Comment: Ok, now we see one imoprtant thing: "error at sending" + "automatic retries". This message bears "warning" class. Is it the only message in the log? Does the service actually try again? Does it try&fail constantly and does it repeat this message constantly? If so, maybe there's something wrong with the message itself (no 'title', no 'bad recipient number format' etc). If it tries and succeeds after a few retries, maybe everything is OK and you just have a bad telephone line or faulty modem? If it does not retry - check the service configuration, is there a limit of attempts? Or maybe it's off?

Comment: The Fax Service provided by Microsoft, does try and resend the fax, but it does fail again.

Comment: There was a guy here with same error code that found a solution : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/88a6ea68-f476-4231-822f-27fabe59f458/error-80040154-retreiving-com-class-factory?forum=vbgeneral Maybe it can guide to the right direction to search.

Comment: Have a look also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197506/how-to-repair-comexception-error-80040154

Comment: @RickyStam I haven't a problem with registering the DLL, as I've now installed the Fax Service on the Windows 2008 server.  The issue is the fax failing to send once it is in the Windows 2003 queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a problem with the file you are attaching as content. I would try adding a file that you have created manually outside of the console app and see if that sends without a problem. If that works then you have at least narrowed the problem down a lot and can concentrate on how the file is created.

Comment: Thanks.  I tracked down the problem to be related to the text which was being written to the txt file.  It appears that there was some problem with converting a byte array using encoding.UTF8.

Comment: @Tommo1977 I am facing a similar issue. Could you please post how you determined the issue was with a byte array and how you resolved it? Thanks

Comment: What is your set-up in terms of Operating Systems for the client and server ?

Comment: The Fax service is running on a Windows Server 2003. The client is a JNI Java application which sends faxes, running on the same machine. We are seeing this error on 2003 server and Win 8.1 operating systems: ezjcom.JComException: Exception occurred. (0x80020009)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/29 14:25:20 |  at FaxCom.IFaxDoc.Send(Native Method) /ngggg

Comment: The error went away on Win 2003 Server after installing Desktop Experience and then came back. I am testing manually with Fax and Scan, and whenever I attach a JPEG, Fax and Scan reports an error. I attempted to define a PrintTo function in the registry for JPEG but it doesn't help. Fax and Scan has no issues sending out certain TIF attachments which is what I am investigating now. Event Viewer reports the error above when attaching a JPEG.

Answer (score 0):

> So the issue isn't with the modem.

Troubleshooting problems get to be difficult when you eliminate the *one* source of the problem.  Of course it is a modem issue, you've verified that everything, up to the modem, works properly.  But yes, it gets to be difficult once it arrives at the modem okay, the fax protocol just doesn't have great ways to provide diagnostics.  Something as simple as the receiver thinking that you are sending it a spam fax with way too many pages cannot be diagnosed.  It unceremoniously hangs up the phone and that's the end of it.

Following the troubleshooting guidelines in the [Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736119%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  Especially take the next step, the one that the event log message recommends you take but you appear not to have taken.  I'll quote it from the article:

> To access the fax activity log:
>
> - To open Windows Explorer, right-click Start, and then click Explore.
> - In the left pane, click the disk that contains the operating system.
> - On the toolbar, click Organize, click Folder and Search Options, click the View tab, and then click Show Hidden Files and Folders. Close the dialog box.
> - In Windows Explorer, navigate to %systemdrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows NT\MSFax\ActivityLog.
> - View the file InboxLog.txt. Each row in InboxLog.txt is an incoming fax job. In the row for a given failed incoming fax transmission, review the Status and Extended Status fields for information about the failure.

If still necessary, ask more questions about this at the [StackExchange site for server admins](https://serverfault.com/), the one site where you can expect to find people that have dealt with fax problems before.

Comment: Thanks Hans, but unfortunately when looking at the log file (that is set to high logging), it doesn't give me any useful information with regards the fatal error.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean it is not useful information to *you* so it shouldn't be useful to *anybody*?  Don't keep it a secret when you ask about this at serverfault.com.  They will insist on you telling them **exactly** what it says.  I would.