# Failed getting class factory de COM of component with CLSID {A9E69610-B80D-11D0-B9B9-00A0C922E750} error: 80040154 Class not Registered

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I am a student, and today on my class when I tryed to run a project with WCF Test client, the visual Sutdio 2019 retrieves me this error:

```
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:54417/ServiceBookStore.svc 
If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  
For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: http://localhost:54417/ServiceBookStore.svc
```

My teacher and I tryed to solve the problem, I had search for a solution but I didn't found too much things. I tryed to uninstall VS 2019 but didnt work so well

Print with error:

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Google for this guid a9e69610-b80d-11d0-b9b9-00a0c922e750 (CLSID_MSAdminBase) . This is related to your IIS install (not installed, not started, needs repair, etc.).

Comment: See this case, [Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036856/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-xxxx-failed-due-to-t/3348181). It maybe helps you.

Comment: Please share your ```webconfig``` file

Comment: On what version of windows do you get this error? Also, is it a server or workstation?

Comment: Check this answer, Hope this will work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7198157/13368495

Comment: This can depend on what you are trying to do. You can improve this question by including code (Github link), your environment(os, .net version)

Comment: Sry but anything worked well! I think I need to format my computer

Comment: I apply all latest update to visual studio 2022 through Visual Studio Installer, In "Visual Studio Installer" -> "Modify" -> checked "ASP.NET and web development" option -> and checked sub options such as "Window Communication Foundation", ".NET Framework 4.6.2-4.7.1 development tool". Problem resolved for my WCF service project lunched in Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same issue while setting up a new Windows 11 virtual. For me, the solution was to enable IIS via Windows features (https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-enable-iis-internet-information-services-on-windows-11.html)

Comment: This post is some time old, however, my problem had to do with the special characters in my name that somehow prevented me from proceeding.
So I can't mark your answer as a correct answer because I cannot even test it anymore, but it will stay here, and who knows if it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your service was built against `Any CPU`, causing you error on `64-bit` where you are using COM components. You need to build it `x86`.

The application is probably running as a `32-bit` process which is why it can use the component. Build your solution against `x86` will force your service to run as `32-bit`.

> Open Visual studio > project properties > in the Build tab > platform target =X86

[image]

Another Solution:

> Open Visual studio > project properties > Build > "Prefer 32-bit" uncheck this. (If it is checked).

Comment: Sry but I had tryed that before, and doesnt work at all! I searched for this problem and it sounds like a DLL missing or something

Comment: answer edited. please check another solution...

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but didnt work! Maybe its something with my computer

Comment: @GonçaloBastos can you please share your ```web.config```, I think your project have multiple issue...