# Registering 32-bit DLL on 64 bit system

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com

I am working with some test code to create Visio documents.  I am using Visual Studio 2010 on Window 7 64 bit.  When I run my program and attempt to create the new Visio application object in the program I get thie following exception:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00021A20-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Here's the code that causes the exception:

```
Visio.Application va = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application();
```

I verified the project settings are to build a 32-bit application. I have tracked it back to 64-bit Windows can't load the 32-bit .COM Visio dll.  I tried registering the dll using regsvr32 but get an error message that the entry-point DLLregisterserver was not found.  MDSN says this means the file is not a valid .dll.  Nowever I am trying to register the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.dll from the Visual Studio libraries.  Is there a fix for this?  Is there a 64-bit version of the .COM libraries?

Comment: Which version of .net you are using?

Comment: check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021796/error-80040154-class-not-registered-exception-when-initializing-vcprojectengin

Comment: Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit Office?  That's what matters, not the bitness of Windows.

Comment: I am using .NET 4.0.  I already checked the project settings, I am building for 32-bit.  FWIW the same project I have some test code that builds an Excel spreadsheet.  That is also .COM and I assume is also 32-bit.

Comment: You mean, 64 bit Win7 OS, 64 bit office and your applications is 32 bit?

Comment: @David: I'm pretty sure you're going to need to install 32-bit Visio in order to use its Interop assembly from a 32-bit program.

Comment: @Dinesh, yes, 64bit Windows, 64bit office. App is 32-bit.  Some of the people who would use it are still on a 32 bit OS.  If it matters, I got the same error when I changed the project settings to a 64bit app.

Comment: @BenVoigt - that worked. thanks for the tip.  It makes sense that I am calling the application interface which would need to talk to the actual Visio app.

Comment: @David: I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249873). This page explains how to install dlls as on 32 bit system, though you are using 64 bit system

You can find 32-bit version of REGSVR32 on 64 bit system on path-- %systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe.

WoW = stands for Windows on Windows

Comment: I tried both (32 and 64bit) versions of regsvr32 and both fail with the same message.  For now I will assume a corrupt dll file and try getting a clean copy.

Answer (score 0):

The Interop assembly you're trying to load depends on the native Visio DLLs.  In order to load those DLLs in-process, they need to match your process bitness.

So, you'll need to have 32-bit Visio installed.