# error:80040154 on windows 7 64 bit mchine

Tags: c#, windows, 64-bit, runtime-error

I have created on windows application with VS2010 on Windows 7 32bit machine. it is working fine on my production machine.

But When i am installing this application on client's server it generating error "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154."

Client's machine is widows 7 64bit.

i am using dlls to work word, excel and pdf.

Please help me to get out of this problem. i am stucked with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hans solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4021887/2019288)

> There are not many good reasons this would fail, especially the
>   regsvr32 step. Run dumpbin /exports on that dll. If you don't see
>   DllRegisterServer then you've got a corrupt install. It should have
>   more side-effects, you wouldn't be able to build C/C++ projects
>   anymore.
>
> One standard failure mode is running this on a 64-bit operating
>   system. This is 32-bit unmanaged code, you would indeed get the 'class
>   not registered' exception. Project + Properties, Build tab, change
>   Platform Target to x86.