# ASMX to COM call in 64 bit Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, web-services, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to call the COM library method(COM interopablity) from ASMX webservice hosted in `IIS 8.5 & Windows Server 2012 64 bit server`. But the call doesnt respond. I have done the following changes to ensure we are doing the right setup

**1. Enable 32 bit application = true for application pool setup**

**2. Registered the COM in the following locations
  C:\Windows\System32 & C:\Windows\SysWoW64**

**3. Tried compile the webservice project to target X86 configuration**

**4. Changed the execution timeout for web service to 10 mins**

**5. Did setup application pool identity which worked for my windows application**

But none of the above works.

> Just to verify .Net and COM communication, I have created the windows
>   application to call the same method and it works when I compile the
>   project in X86 platform.
>
> If I compile the windows application to target platform to Any CPU, I
>   get the same issue like calling it via ASMX web service. Its not
>   responding to the call.
>
> Finaly, It looks like it is working for windows application target x86
>   platform. But no idea, why it is not working from asmx service when I
>   set Enable 32 bit application.

Could you help me to identify what could be the wrong with ASMX to COM call?

***Referenced:***

[Error 80040154 (Class not registered exception) when initializing VCProjectEngineObject (Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.dll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021796/error-80040154-class-not-registered-exception-when-initializing-vcprojectengin/4021887#4021887)

[How to repair COMException error 80040154?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197506/how-to-repair-comexception-error-80040154)

**Note:** I was getting COM exception 80040154 error when COM was not installed on C:\Windows\System32 folder. Now not getting this error but call not responds.

Server is 64bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the COM server you invoke, you may need to [specify an Identity for an Application Pool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) if the COM application requires a user profile, or check the app pool's `Load User Profile` property. ([I needed this](https://devio.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/running-32-bit-abcpdf-pro-on-64-bit-windows/) to run ABCpdf, for example)

Comment: Yes. I did setup the application pool identity as you mentioned. I used my windows logon credentials that worked for running the windows application x86 platform build in application pool identity setup.

Comment: Wow!! Great you saved my day :) It worked after setting Load User Profile true :) Cheers.