# Retrieve location from outlook appointment for a C# addin

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

Good day,
I am trying to create an outlook addin, that retrieves fields entered in the new appointment tab when creating an outlook meeting, primarily what location they have selected.

When creating a new meeting you are able to select the room (resource) and it displays in the location field.

I need to be able to pull in that location into my C# outlook addin (VSTO) and display it as a string. I am not able to find that reference anywhere.

Everywhere i have looked they have explained how to create a new appointment from C# but not the other way around:

I am not entirely sure this is possible, But i would assume it to look something like: string location = Outlook.AppointmentItem.Resources

The closest i have found would be something like these:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._appointmentitem.resources%28v=office.14%29.aspx And https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._appointmentitem%28v=office.14%29.aspx

But they dont seem to work.
Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AppointmentItem.Location` property. Or loop through AppointmentItem.Recipients collection and look for Recipient.Type = olBCC resources are BCC recipients).

Comment: Thankyou so much for the speedy reply Dmitry, however i get the following issue:

Error CS0117 'AppointmentItem' does not contain a definition for 'location'

Comment: Of course it does. Have you tried "Location" (note the uppercase "L:)?

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, much appreciated!
only having an issue with this now, i have tried to make my string static :
static string LocationValue = Outlook.AppointmentItem.Location;

Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property '_AppointmentItem.Location'

Comment: Just as the compiler error suggests, you are invoking a static property. There is no such thing in COM - you must access Location property on a particular **instance** of the Outlook.AppointmentItem object.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry
`Outlook.AppointmentItem _loc = new Outlook.AppointmentItem();
                string LocationValue = _loc.Location;`

I can compile now with no errors, however i get an error during run-time:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID ...failed
80040154 Class not registered

Comment: I have tried this:
changed the platform code, however i still get the same error:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021796/error-80040154-class-not-registered-exception-when-initializing-vcprojectengin/4021887#4021887

Comment: AppointmentItem is not creatable, you need to retrieve it from Outlook. If it is being displayed, use Application.AcrtiveInspector.CurrentItem.

Comment: Apologies Dmitry, I understand i need to retrieve it from outlook, but i am not sure how to format the Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem in relation to the location/resource.  Do i replace the previous object completely with the active inspector? I simply want to view the outlooks appointment's location in a string...

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Location will give you what you want.

Comment: Could you give me this  ActiveInspector in some code sample, because I don't understand how this works.

Comment: I am not sure what you are having troubles with. In a VSTO addin, you can use Globals.ThisAddIn.Application to access the Outlook.Application object. Once you have Application, check that  Application.ActiveInspector is not null. Cast  Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem to ApppointmentItem object. Use ApppointmentItem.Location.